# Numerical solution of nonlinear water wave equation with Dirchlet-Neumann operator

Tags: fourier-transform

I've been trying now for quite some time to numerically solve the nonlinear water wave equation [Craig and Sulem, JCP (1993)] by using FFT to discretize the space. I present my code below. By testing different aspects of the code, I have narrowed down the problem to the implementation of Dirchlet-Neumann operator (DNO). I have tried implementing the operator in two different ways but I get large error values when I compare the numerical operator with the exact operator as suggested in Xu and Guyenne (2009) JCP section 4.1, see the line `print([np.linalg.norm(G_eta_x_xeta - G_eta_J_x_xeta[j]) for j in range(J)])` in my code below. I suspect the issue is with how I have implemented DNO in `def DNO(self, u, J, Dx):`.

The nonlinear water wave is a PDE which models fluid flow in a channel of finite or infinite depth. DNO operator $G(\eta)$ relates the boundary values of the velocity potential $\phi$ on the surface $\eta$ to the values of $\partial_n \phi$. The water wave equations read

$$\eta_t = G(\eta) \xi, \\
\xi_t = -\frac{1}{2(1+\eta_x^2)} \left(\xi_x^2 -(G(\eta)\xi)^2 -2\eta_x \xi_x G(\eta) \xi \right) -g \eta.$$
Here $g$ is the constant of gravitational acceleration and $(\eta, \xi)$ is the solution of the PDE. The code presented below tries to evaluete $G(\eta)\xi$ and other spatial derivaties in the Fourier space using FFT.

````
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed May 31 11:59:41 2023

@author: 
"""

import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft, fftfreq, fftshift
import scipy.special
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import ode
from pylab import r_, c_

class WaterWaveSimulation:
    def __init__(self, N, L):
        self.N = N
        self.L = L        
            
        # Water-wave discretization and initial condition of Gaussian profile
        # self.L = 400
        # self.x = np.linspace(-self.L/2, self.L/2, N, endpoint=False)
        # self.dx = self.L/self.N
        
        
        # self.u0 = 0.1 * np.cosh(0.27 * (self.x + 80)) ** (-2)
        # self.v0 = 1 * np.cosh(0.27 * (self.x + 80)) ** (-2)
        
        
        # Water-wave discretization and initial condition of exponential modulated cosine
        self.L = 2*np.pi
        self.x = np.linspace(0, self.L, N, endpoint=False)
        self.dx = self.L/self.N
        
        self.u0 = 0.01 * np.exp(-4/3 * (self.x - np.pi) ** 2) * np.cos(10 * self.x)
        self.v0 = np.zeros_like(self.u0)
        
        self.y0 = r_[self.u0, self.v0]

    def waterWaveEquation(self, t, y):
        # Parameters
        self.g = 9.81  # Acceleration due to gravity
        self.d = 1 # Water depth
        
        # Compute the Dirichlet-Neumann operator of the wave profile
        dydt = self.rhs(y)
        
        # Compute the derivative of the wave profile
        return dydt

    def rhs(self, input):
        
        # Fourier frequency vector
        kappa = fftfreq(self.N, d=self.dx) * 2 * np.pi
        # kappa = fftshift(kappa)
        # k[self.N//2] = 0
        
        # Perform Fourier transform
        u = input[:self.N]
        v = input[self.N:]
        
        u_hat = fft(u)
        v_hat = fft(v)
        # u_hat[self.N//2] = 0
        # v_hat[self.N//2] = 0
        
        # Compute spatial derivatives in the Fourier domain
        Dx = kappa * 1j
        Dx2 = Dx ** 2            
                
        J = 6 # sum_j G_j for j from 0 to (J-1)
        G_list = self.DNO(u_hat, J, Dx)
        G_u = sum(G_list)
        G_u_x_v = ifft(G_u * v_hat).real
        
        Dx_u = ifft(Dx * u_hat).real
        Dx_v = ifft(Dx * v_hat).real
        
        # Nonlinear water-wave rhs
        # Apply the Dirichlet-Neumann operator in the Fourier domain
        output = r_[G_u_x_v, \
                    -self.g * u \
                    - 1/(2 * (1 + (Dx_u)**2)) \
                    * ((Dx_v)**2 - (G_u_x_v)**2 \
                        - 2 * Dx_u * Dx_v * G_u_x_v)]

        return output
        
    def DNO(self, u, J, Dx):
        # Compute the Dirichlet-Neumann operator in the Fourier domain
        
        D = -1j * Dx
        T = np.tanh(self.d * D)
        G0 = D * T
        G_list = [None]*J
        
        # DNO expansion
        # G1 = D * (u - T * u * T) * D
        # G2 = -0.5 * D * (D * u**2 * T \
        #                 + T * u**2 * D \
        #                 - 2 * T * u * D * T * u * T \
        #                 ) * D
        
        # G_list = [G0, G1, G2]
        # return G_list
        
        # Xu and Guyenne 2009
        # def DNO_Xu():
        
        # factorial_J_inv = 1/scipy.special.factorial(range(J))
        # # factorial_2xrms_inv = [1/scipy.special.factorial(2 * (r-s)) for s in range(r)]
                
        # for j in range(J):
        #     if j == 0:
        #         G_list[j] = G0
                
        #     elif j % 2 == 0: # even
        #         r = j // 2
                
        #         G_list[j] = factorial_J_inv[j] * G0 * (Dx ** 2) ** (r-1) * Dx * u ** (2*r) * Dx \
        #                     - sum([1/np.math.factorial(2 * (r-s)) * (Dx **2) ** (r-s) * u ** (2 * (r-s)) * G_list[2*s] for s in range(r)]) \
        #                     - sum([1/np.math.factorial(2 * (r-s) - 1) * G0 * (Dx **2) ** (r-s-1) * u ** (2 * (r-s) -1) * G_list[2*s+1] for s in range(r)])
                
        #     elif j % 2 == 1: # odd
        #         r = (j + 1) // 2
                
        #         G_list[j] = factorial_J_inv[j] * (Dx ** 2) ** (r-1) * Dx * u ** (2*r -1) * Dx \
        #                     - sum([1/np.math.factorial(2 * (r-s) -1) * G0 * (Dx **2) ** (r-s-1) * u ** (2 * (r-s) -1) * G_list[2*s] for s in range(r)]) \
        #                     - sum([1/np.math.factorial(2 * (r-s-1)) * (Dx **2) ** (r-s-1) * u ** (2 * (r-s-1)) * G_list[2*s+1] for s in range(r-1)])
                
        # return G_list
        
        # Craig and Sulem 1993
        # def DNO_Craig():
        
        factorial_J_inv = 1/scipy.special.factorial(range(J))
        # factorial_2xrms_inv = [1/scipy.special.factorial(2 * (r-s)) for s in range(r)]
                
        for j in range(J):
            if j == 0:
                G_list[j] = G0
                
            elif j % 2 == 0: # even
                
                G_list[j] = factorial_J_inv[j] * ((u ** j) * (D ** (j+1)) * T - 1j * (Dx * (u ** j)) * (D ** j) * T) \
                            - sum([1/np.math.factorial(j - l) * u ** (j-l) * D ** (j-l) * G_list[l] for l in range(0, j, 2)]) \
                            - sum([1/np.math.factorial(j - l) * u ** (j-l) * D ** (j-l) * G_list[l] * T for l in range(1, j, 2)])
                
            elif j % 2 == 1: # odd
                
                G_list[j] = factorial_J_inv[j] * ((u ** j) * (D ** (j+1)) - 1j * (Dx * (u ** j)) * (D ** j)) \
                            - sum([1/np.math.factorial(j - l) * u ** (j-l) * D ** (j-l) * G_list[l] for l in range(1, j, 2)]) \
                            - sum([1/np.math.factorial(j - l) * u ** (j-l) * D ** (j-l) * G_list[l] * T for l in range(0, j, 2)])
                            
        return G_list

    def simulate(self, tspan):
        r = ode(self.waterWaveEquation).set_integrator('dopri5')
        r.set_initial_value(self.y0, tspan[0])
        
        # Storage for results
        t_values = [tspan[0]]
        y_values = [self.y0]
        
        dt = 0.05
        while r.successful() and r.t < tspan[1]:
            r.integrate(r.t + dt)
            # print(r.t + dt)
            t_values.append(r.t)
            y_values.append(r.y)
        
        if (not r.successful()) or (r.t < tspan[1]):
            print('Integration incomplete')
        
        t_values = np.array(t_values)
        y_values = np.array(y_values)
        
        # Plot the wave profiles at different times
        %matplotlib qt
        plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
        plt.style.use('seaborn')
        plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18})
        
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        for i in range(len(t_values)):
            ax.clear()
            ax.plot(self.x, y_values[i][:self.N])
            ax.set_xlim([self.x[0], self.x[-1]])
            # ax.set_ylim([-1.5, 1.5])
            ax.set_title('Water Wave Profile at t = {:.2f}'.format(t_values[i]))
            ax.set_xlabel('x')
            ax.set_ylabel(r'$\eta$')
            plt.pause(0.01)
        
            plt.show()


def _test_DNO():
    # Test for accurancy of the DNO operator
    # Xu and Gueyene (JCP) 2009
    # Comprison of the exact and truncated DN operator
    
    # Get the system parameters
    sim = WaterWaveSimulation(N, L)
    
    a = 0.1
    g = 9.81
    sim.d = d = 1
    
    omega = np.sqrt(g * np.tanh(d) )
    phi = lambda x, y: a*g/omega * np.cosh(y + d) * np.sin(x) / np.cosh(d)
    eta = a * np.cos(sim.x)
    
    xeta = lambda x: phi(x, eta)
    
    # Exact DNO
    G_eta_x_xeta = a * g / np.cosh(d) \
                    * (np.sinh(eta + d) * np.sin(sim.x) - a * np.sin(sim.x) * np.cosh(eta + d) * np.cos(sim.x) )
    
    # Fourier frequency vector
    kappa = fftfreq(sim.N, d=sim.dx) * 2 * np.pi
    # kappa = fftshift(kappa)
    # k[sim.N//2] = 0
    
    eta_hat = fft(eta)
    xeta_hat = fft(xeta(sim.x))
    
    # Compute spatial derivatives in the Fourier domain
    Dx = kappa * 1j
    Dx2 = Dx ** 2            
            
    J = 6 # sum_j G_j for j from 0 to (J-1)
    G_list = sim.DNO(eta_hat, J, Dx)
    G_eta_J = [sum(G_list[:j]) for j in range(J)]
    
    # Numerical DNO
    G_eta_J_x_xeta = [ifft(G_eta_J[j] * xeta_hat).real for j in range(J)]
    
    # difference between exact and truncated DNO
    # This error is large for all three implementation of DNOs
    print([np.linalg.norm(G_eta_x_xeta - G_eta_J_x_xeta[j]) for j in range(J)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Usage example
    N = 2**8  # Number of points in the domain
    L = 2*np.pi  # Length of the domain
    tspan = [0, 50]  # Time span
    
    # simulation = WaterWaveSimulation(N, L)
    # simulation.simulate(tspan)
    
    _test_DNO()
```
````

Comment: What is the nonlinear water wave equation? What is DNO?